# Как экранировать знак вопроса в htaccess?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

Нужно изменить url из вида

`http://site.com/?one`

В вид

`http://site.com/two`

Но такого рода не работают:

`RewriteRule "^\?one$" "two"`

`RewriteRule "^\\?one$" "two"`

`RewriteRule "^[?]one$" "two"`

Как правильно?

Comment: https://artkiev.com/blog/htaccess-regexp.htm, https://hostgid.net/baza-znanii/-htaccess/sintaksis-i-reguljarnye-vyrazhenija-htac.html

Answer (score 1):

`?abc` это не путь, к которому применяются правила, а `%{QUERY_STRING}`, или GET-параметры запроса. Они не валидируются основной директивой `RewriteRule`. Для проверки следует использовать `RewriteCond`.

В итоге, чтобы преобразовать входяшую ссылку `http://example.com?one` и сделать редирект, например на `http://example.com/two`, следует сделать две вещи.

1. проверить, что `%{QUERY_STRING}` содержит искомый фрагмент
2. убедиться, что путь - корневой

Итого:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =one
RewriteRule ^$ two [R=301,QSD]
```